# 3D effects in website

Tags: css, html

Say I want to make a website, and I want the page to have some sort of a main-area, and it's supposed to be something like an open book,

[image: design explanation]

sort of something like that if I want to make my point, I want the left border to be 100% of the height of whatever the page is going to show, and the right border(the one that's intersecting with the left border of the right page) to be say 90% of the height of it... that's sort of the idea of the design.

I was sure there would be some HTML5 features that would support this since I've seen stuff like this around the internet but I realized it wouldn't be that easy.

I hoped that there would be people with proper knowledge of web design that could help me with this thing

Comment: [https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/introduction.html](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/introduction.html) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This is very good article for page flip functionality with html5 :
http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/create-page-flip-effect-html5-canvas-8112798

Comment: But say I don't want it to be a flip effect, but just static and sitting with that prespective?

Comment: Then use CSS3 `perspective` and `transform`! Be sure to use vendor-prefixes!